# Slow response if accessing php from same public IP

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application that's got a wierd issue when connecting to my web server.

The application initiates a MySQL update via php in exactly the same way as a browser would if you typed the address.

Problem is when there are two iterations of the app running (with separate user accounts) on the same WiFi connection, one of the two will suffer from slow responses from the web server (or the php file) and the other will not.

I can connect 10s of devices if they are on differing internet connections (3G or LTE or other wifi) but if the php is accessed by more than one device from the same public IP the app responds incredibly slowly.

I suppose, before I get into the copy and paste of the php, My question is if you know of any silver bullet solutions based on the  limitations in php, php versions, MySQL or anything that could be causing this?

Test cases:

One app 3G, one app wifi (speed perfect)

One app 3G, one app 3G (speed perfect)

One app 3G, host one 3G client tether (Speed dire)

One app wifi one app wifi (Speed dire)

3G speed 14Mbps
Wifi speed 100Mbps
Server Godaddy shared

Comment: This sounds more like a network issue, I can't imagine how your PHP or SQL server could be poorly affected by ONLY internal users.  But your internal network could have issues, I would start there.

Comment: I don't think this will have anything to do with php/MySQL. It is more likely an issue with web server configuration or even local configuration on the devices you are accessing the application from

Comment: I really have trouble shot the hell out of it network wise, changed location for wifi testing, had Skype convos with people in Germany and the U.S To log devices in while I log in. Separate networks work beautifully but if the devices share the same network (any and all forms of it be that tethering through one another, a LTE modem, wifi etc) the same happens one of the devices will be responsive and the others will slow to a halt.

Comment: If thats the case then its definitely a network issue

Comment: Not sure how you come to that conclusion George. It only occurs when sharing a single public IP not at any other time.

Comment: My guess is that this is a GoDaddy issue. I ran into a similar problem: in order to help block spammers (at least that's what they say), they have a limit for the number of POST requests for a single IP in a 60 second period. This is a bit different, but I wouldn't be surprised if this was a another so-called protective measure against spammers.

Comment: came to the same conclusion, wiresharked it today and 60 seconds is the average, it sucks for me but good for those who want to prevent DDOS.